# In a React project, I have a global script importing a chatbot in my index.html

Tags: reactjs

On a specific page i need to replace the imported elements from this script with another script.
After script1 imports the chatbot element, let's say, on the register component, I want to remove all the elements imported by the script and render another chatbot. After exiting this register component, I want the original script to render again., I need to swap these elements with another script. Upon exiting this page, I want the original script's elements to return.

i also tried remove the script after returning..but only script is removed ,the elements imported by the script remain
`const element = document?.getElementById("chatBot1"); if (element) { element.remove(); } const script = document.createElement('script'); script.textContent = script2; document.body.appendChild(script);`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.